# changing model objects inside controllers to manipulate DOM objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

So I am learning how to use controllers in angularjs and I am stuck. I created a form using html and tested to see if the controller was responding to the html through the data-binded attribute "message". However "enter your details" does not appear under "Add Event" in the browser. Am I missing something in my code? Is there somewhere in the app.module folder where I should declare a constructor? Let me know your thoughts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<h3>Add Event</h3>

<div ng-app='eventForm' name='AddEventForm' ng-submit='AddEvent();' ng-controller='eventsCtrl'>
    {{message}}
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>Event Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="event.Name" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Event Location</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="event.Location" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Event Description</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="event.Description" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="submit" ng-disabled="AddEventForm.$invalid"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

        <script>
        var eventForm = angular.module('eventForm', []);
        eventForm.controller('eventsCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Enter your details';
        $scope.addEvent = function()
        {

        }
    });

        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Same code working fine for me. I copy pasted it. Please check carefully. Secondly there is nothing like using or implementing JavaScript in angularJs . Angular is nothing but a JavaScript library only implemented itself in JavaScript. Every browser is capable of running JavaScript. Nothing special needs to be done

Comment: I just copied and pasted it into jsFiddle and it works but "Enter your details" does not appear in my app. Don't worry ill figure it out. By the way would it make more sense to put all of my javascript in a separate file and reference it with script src?

Comment: yes it makes more sense to put all of your JavaScript in a separate file and then reference that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can like this following

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Add Event</h3>

    <form
      ng-app="eventForm"
      ng-controller="eventsCtrl"
      name="AddEventForm"
      ng-submit="AddEvent()"
    >
      {{ message }}
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Event Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="event.Name" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Event Location</td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="event.Location" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Event Description</td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="event.Description" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="AddEventForm.$invalid">
              Submit
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>

    <script>
      var eventForm = angular.module("eventForm", []);
      eventForm.controller("eventsCtrl", function($scope, $log) {
        $scope.message = "Enter your details";
        $scope.AddEvent = function() {
          $log.log($scope.event);
        };
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code but the message still doesn't show in my project. I know... I am as confused as you are.

Comment: @Jonathan, You want to show the `Event` data into `message`?

Comment: @RakeshKumar Yes, I wanted to see the message as a test that my html was responding to my javascript

Answer (score 1):

I think you should to use `form` tag in this situation:

```
<form ng-app='eventForm' name='AddEventForm' ng-submit='AddEvent();' ng-controller='eventsCtrl'>
```